# JSF- passing a parameter to valuechangelistener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameter-passing, valuechangelistener

I have a litte radiobutton like this :

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{test.answer}" valueChangeListener="#{TestService.changeanswer}" immediate="true" id="answer">
 <f:selectItem  itemValue="A" itemLabel="Absolutely True"/>
 <f:selectItem  itemValue="B" itemLabel="True"/>
 <f:selectItem  itemValue="C" itemLabel="Partially True"/>
 <f:selectItem  itemValue="D" itemLabel="Not True"/>
 <f:selectItem  itemValue="E" itemLabel="Definitely Not True"/>
 <f:ajax event="change" process="answer"></f:ajax></h:selectOneRadio>
```

And my listener is like that :

```
public void changeanswer(ValueChangeEvent vcEvent) { 
System.out.println("comeon= " + vcEvent.getOldValue()); 
System.out.println("comeon= " + vcEvent.getNewValue());}
```

I would like to pass a parameter to the changeanswer method.For example I want to pass the questionid to the changeanswer function. I need to make some arrangements in it.

How can I do that?

Many many many thanks in advance.

Brad - the Rookie..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seeing how the component values are bound, I bet that it's inside a datatable. If that is indeed the case, you can use [`DataModel#getRowData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html#getRowData%28%29) to obtain the current row. Add a `DataModel` property to the `TestService` bean like follows:

```
private List<Question> questions;
private DataModel<Question> questionModel;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    questions = getItSomehow();
    questionModel = new ListDataModel<Question>(questions);
}

public void change(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Question currentQuestion = questionModel.getRowData();
    // ...
}
```

and change the view as follows:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{TestService.questionModel}" var="test">
```

---

That said, I'd suggest to use more sensible variable names than `TestService`, `test` and `change()`, like `Questionaire`, `question` and `changeAnswer()` respectively. This makes the code more self-documenting.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It was a datatable. And you saved my week. Thanks hero!

Comment: That was VERY VERY helpful BaluC! Thanks a lot! :) I didn't know there exists something like DataModel class!!! This is SO useful! +1 for Brad's question as well.

Comment: @Nikhil: you're welcome. You may find this article useful as well: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html It contains a CRUD example utilizing `<h:dataTable>`, `DataModel<E>` and `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: @BalusC: Today I found your name at about 100 answers to important jsf issues - Thanks for it

Answer (score 20):

You can use the f:attribute tag to send any data to the ValueChangeListener:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{test.answer}"
                  valueChangeListener="#{TestService.changeanswer}"
                  immediate="true" id="answer">
    <f:attribute name="myattribute" value="#{test.questionid}" />
    <f:selectItem  itemValue="A" itemLabel="Absolutely True"/>
    ...
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

If we suppose questionId is an Integer, then you can receive the data the following way:

```
public void changeanswer(ValueChangeEvent vcEvent) { 
  Integer questionId =
    (Integer) ((UIInput) vcEvent.getSource()).getAttributes().get("myattribute");
```