# About a checkbox on datatable

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I want to use checkbox on datatable like that :

```
 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="selectBooleanCheckbox" valueChangeListener="#{CompletedInventoriesBean.changeUID}" value="#{CompletedInventoriesBean.isChecked(userinventorieswithuser.id)}" id="chkUser">
           <f:ajax event="change" process="chkUser"></f:ajax>
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

My uids are on the Session. And I want to user that clicks checkbox and I am adding or removing that ids on the session.

There is no problem, I could handle the values on the session an beans.

But during the click on the checkboxes, I get JavaScript alert like below:

> serverError: class javax.faces.component.UpdateModelExcepton/sections/completed.xhtml @29,244
>   value="#{CompletedInventoriesBean.isChecked(userinventorieswithuser.id)}":
>   Property 'isChecked' not found on type main.com.brad.services.CompletedInventoriesBean

my isChecked method like that :

```
public boolean isChecked(int z) {
    boolean exist = false;
    for(int i=0; i < selectedSessionUI.getSessionInventories().size(); i++) {
        if (selectedSessionUI.getSessionInventories().get(i) == z) exist = true;
    }
    return exist;
}
```

Why I get this alert? This is the only think that I stucked in that page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind the `value` attribute to a method taking arguments. It should be bound to a property which is represented by a pure getter and setter.

In this particular case, you'd rather like to use a `Map<Long, Boolean>` instead.

```
private Map<Long, Boolean> checked = new HashMap<Long, Boolean>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    for (int id : selectedSessionUI.getSessionInventories()) {
        checked.put(Long.valueOf(id), true);
    }
}

public Map<Long, Boolean> getChecked() {
    return checked;
}
```

in combination with

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{CompletedInventoriesBean.checked[userinventorieswithuser.id]}">
```

To collect all checked rows, just loop through `checked` map in the action method.

*(no setter is required since `[]` will use `put()` and `get()` on `Map` itself)*

Comment: I lack words to thank you. You just gave me what I exactly was looking for. And you made me understand the matter much better. I am so much grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you can't pass parameters to the valueChangeListener method. Similar question to this one was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954652/jsf-passing-a-parameter-to-valuechangelistener).

More on this can be found [under this link](http://www.therichwebexperience.com/blog/max_katz/2009/02/how_to_delete_a_row_in_jsf).